# Using a repeater with inputText field

Tags: apex, visualforce, inputtext, data-repeater

I'm creating a custom community chatter answers page and I have multiple questions with answers in them using an apex repeater. The problem is that because it's repeating inputText field (for posting replies), it is using the same value variable, like this (postAnswer):

**VF Page**

```
<apex:form>
<apex:variable var="questionIndex" value="{!0}" id="index" />
    <apex:repeat value="{!wrapperQuestions}" var="currentQuestion">
    <div class="articleWrapper clearfix">
    <apex:outputPanel>
        <article class="whiteCard socialCard">
            <span class="category">Answers</span>
            <div class="clearfix">
                <div class="profilePic centerAlign col _1of6">
                    <apex:image url="{!currentQuestion.question.CreatorFullPhotoUrl}" />
                    <span class="heading7">Frequent Poster</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col colPad content _5of6">
                    <h1 class="heading1">{!currentQuestion.question.Title}</h1>
                    <h2 class="heading6">
                        <strong>{!currentQuestion.question.CreatedBy.Name}</strong> &mdash;
                        <apex:outputText value="{0,date,E MMM d, yyyy 'at' hh:mma z}">
                            <apex:param value="{!currentQuestion.question.CreatedDate}"/>
                        </apex:outputText><br />
                    </h2>
                    <p>{!currentQuestion.question.Body}</p>
                    <div class="rightAlign">
                        <button type="button" class="readMore">Read More <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <div class="whiteCard newPost">
        <apex:inputText id="postAnswer" value="{!currentQuestion.postAnswer}" html-placeholder="What do you have to say?" />
        <apex:commandButton action="{!saveReply}" styleClass="post" value="Post" rerender="replies,index">
            <apex:param name="qId"
                value="{!currentQuestion.question.Id}"
                assignTo="{!qId}"/>
            <apex:param name="questionIndex"
                value="{!questionIndex}"
                assignTo="{!questionIndex}"/>
        </apex:commandButton>
    </div>
    <apex:repeat value="{!currentQuestion.bestReply}" var="bestReply">
        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!bestReply.Id != null}">
            <div class="replies col colRight _3of4">
                <div class="whiteCard socialCard">
                    <span class="category">Best Answer <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i></span>
                    <div class="clearfix">
                        <div class="profilePic centerAlign col _1of6">
                            <apex:image url="{!bestReply.CreatorSmallPhotoUrl}" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col colPad content _5of6">
                            <h2 class="heading6">
                                <strong>{!bestReply.CreatedBy.Name}</strong> &mdash;
                                <apex:outputText value="{0,date,E MMM d, yyyy 'at' hh:mma z}">
                                    <apex:param value="{!bestReply.createdDate}"/>
                                </apex:outputText>
                            </h2>
                            {!bestReply.Body}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:repeat>
    <apex:repeat value="{!currentQuestion.replies}" var="currentReply" id="replies">
        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!currentReply.Id != null}">
            <div class="replies col colRight _3of4">
                <div class="whiteCard socialCard">
                    <div class="clearfix">
                        <div class="profilePic centerAlign col _1of6">
                            <apex:image url="{!currentReply.CreatorSmallPhotoUrl}" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col colPad content _5of6">
                            <h2 class="heading6">
                                <strong>{!currentReply.CreatedBy.Name}</strong> &mdash;
                                <apex:outputText value="{0,date,E MMM d, yyyy 'at' hh:mma z}">
                                    <apex:param value="{!currentReply.createdDate}"/>
                                </apex:outputText>
                            </h2>
                            {!currentReply.Body}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:repeat>
    </div>
    <apex:variable var="questionIndex" value="{!questionIndex + 1}"/>
</apex:repeat>
```

Since it's the same value, I can only get the value of the last input field and none of the other ones in my controller.

Here's my controller. It doesn't have much. Just to test that I'm getting the correct values:

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class RL_HubHome {
    public Id currentUserId {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public String currentUserName {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public String currentUserOrganization {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public String currentUserProfileImageLarge {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public Integer totalSubscribedGroups {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public Integer totalSubscribedAnswers {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public Integer totalCases {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public Integer totalIdeas {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public String strFilteredDataCategories {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public List < WrapperQuestions > wrapperQuestions {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public WrapperQuestions wq {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public List < Question > questionsList {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public list < String > listSubscriptionCategories {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public String postAnswer {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public String qId {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public Integer questionIndex {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public String searchCategory;

    public String getsearchCategory() {
        return searchCategory;
    }

    public void setsearchCategory(String searchCategory) {
        this.searchCategory = searchCategory;
    }

    public RL_HubHome() {
        init();
    }

    public Pagereference redirectUnAuthenticatedUser() {
        if (Userinfo.getUserType() != 'CspLitePortal' && Userinfo.getUserType() != 'PowerCustomerSuccess') {
            return new Pagereference('/Signin');
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void init() {
        currentUserId = Userinfo.getUserId();
        currentUserName = Userinfo.getName();
        currentUserOrganization = Userinfo.getOrganizationName();
        currentUserProfileImageLarge = [SELECT FullPhotoUrl FROM User WHERE Id = : currentUserId].FullPhotoUrl;
        totalSubscribedGroups = [SELECT count()
        FROM CollaborationGroupFeed
        WHERE ParentId IN(
        SELECT CollaborationGroupId
        FROM CollaborationGroupMember
        WHERE MemberId = : currentUserId)];
        totalSubscribedAnswers = [SELECT count()
        FROM QuestionSubscription q
        WHERE q.SubscriberId = : currentUserId];
        totalCases = [SELECT count()
        FROM Case
        WHERE IsDeleted = false
        AND IsClosed = false
        AND CreatedById = : currentUserId];
        totalIdeas = [SELECT count()
        FROM Idea i
        WHERE i.CreatedById = : currentUserId];
        strFilteredDataCategories = RL_FetchDataCategoryOfLoggedInUser.dataCatgeries();
        wrapperQuestions = getQuestionsReplies();

        listSubscriptionCategories = new List < String > ();

        listSubscriptionCategories.add('All');
        listSubscriptionCategories.add('Answers');
        listSubscriptionCategories.add('Ideas');
        listSubscriptionCategories.add('Groups');
    }

    public List < Question > getQuestions() {
        if (questionsList == null) {
            questionsList = new List < Question > ();
            for (Question q: [SELECT q.Id, q.CreatorSmallPhotoUrl, q.CreatorFullPhotoUrl, q.CreatorName, q.CreatedDate, q.CreatedById, q.CreatedBy.Name, q.Body, q.Title, q.BestReplyId FROM Question q]) {
                // As each question is processed we create a new WrapperQuestions object and add it to the questionList
                questionsList.add(q);
            }
        }
        return questionsList;
    }

    public List < WrapperQuestions > getQuestionsReplies() {
        WrapperQuestions wrapperQuestions;
        List < WrapperQuestions > wrapperList = new List < WrapperQuestions > ();
        if (questionsList == null) {
            List < Question > questionsList = getQuestions();
            List < Reply > replies;
            for (Question q: questionsList) {
                Reply bestReply = null;
                List < Reply > bestReplyList = new List < Reply > ();
                List < reply > repliesList = new List < reply > ();
                // As each question is processed we create a new WrapperQuestions object and add it to the repliesList
                bestReplyList = [SELECT Id, CreatedDate, CreatedById, CreatedBy.Name, CreatorName, QuestionId, Body, UpVotes, DownVotes, CreatorSmallPhotoUrl FROM Reply WHERE QuestionId = : q.Id AND Id = : q.BestReplyId];
                if (!bestReplyList.isEmpty()) {
                    bestReply = bestReplyList[0];
                }
                replies = [SELECT Id, CreatedDate, CreatedById, CreatedBy.Name, CreatorName, QuestionId, Body, UpVotes, DownVotes, CreatorSmallPhotoUrl FROM Reply WHERE QuestionId = : q.Id AND Id != : q.BestReplyId ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC];
                if (replies != null) {
                    for (Reply r: replies) {
                        repliesList.add(r);
                    }
                } else {
                    repliesList = null;
                }
                wrapperQuestions = new WrapperQuestions(q, bestReply, repliesList);
                wrapperList.add(wrapperQuestions);
            }
        }
        return wrapperList;
    }

    public class WrapperQuestions // wrapper class to handle multiple objects.
    {
        public Question question {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public Reply bestReply {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public List < Reply > replies {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public String postAnswer {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public WrapperQuestions(Question q, Reply bestR, List < Reply > r) {
            bestReply = bestR;
            question = q;
            replies = r;
        }
    }

    public void saveReply() {
        System.Debug('====qId===' + qId);
        //System.Debug('===postAnswer===' + wrapperQuestions[questionIndex].postAnswer);
        postAnswer = wrapperQuestions[questionIndex].postAnswer;
        System.Debug('===postAnswer===' + postAnswer);
        try {
            // Add a reply to this question.
            Reply r = new Reply(
            QuestionId = qId,
            Body = postAnswer);
            insert r;
        } catch (DmlException e) {
            System.debug('An unexpected error has occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Before you're done with this page, refactor the SOQL queries for `bestReplyList` and `replies` out of that `for` loop over `questionsList`. Queries in loops is a bad practice.

Comment: Thanks Mark. What is the alternative to this? I'm trying to get all replies related to all questions. The only way that I can think of going about it is to have a repeater inside a repeater to display the values.

Comment: Rather than having multiple SOQL queries with the conditions `WHERE QuestionId = : q.Id AND Id = : q.BestReplyId`, add the question IDs and best reply IDs to Sets beforehand making a single query with the condition `WHERE questionId IN :setOfQuestionIds AND Id IN :setOfBestReplyIds`.  You now have all the relevant records with a single query, and can process them with Apex.  See SFDC99's series of posts for details - http://www.sfdc99.com/2014/01/20/soql-queries-inside-loops/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there's a single `postAnswer` for multiple `wrapperQuestions`.  The way to fix this is to move `postAnswer` into your wrapper class so that it becomes a property of each `wrapperQuestion`.  You can then change the `value` of the `apex:inputText` to `{!currentQuestion.postAnswer}`.

When you call `saveReply()`, each `wrapperQuestion` will now have its own `postAnswer`.  To know which one has been submitted, you need to submit the `wrapperQuestion`'s position index in the list.  To do this, add the following:

Before the opening tag of `<apex:repeat>` -

```
<apex:variable var="questionIndex" value="{!1}" />
```

Before the closing tag of `<apex:repeat>` -

```
<apex:variable var="questionIndex" value="{!questionIndex + 1}"/>
```

Add `questionIndex` as another `<apex:param>` to the `<apex:commandButton>`, then in the `saveReply()` method your answer will be `wrapperQuestions[questionIndex].postAnswer`.

Comment: Thanks Rob, but I think I was unclear. The inputText field is supposed to be empty and filled in by the user and then the value of this needs to be passed to the controller.

Comment: Understood.  In that case, you may need to change the type of `postAnswer` from a String to a list of Strings.  It's hard to tell from the code above.  Can you post more of the page (specifically the `<apex:repeat>`) and the controller please?

Comment: Added my controller, but it doesn't show much. I'm just using the button to debug what values are passed back. In my case I need to pass back the reply and the questionId - So I can post the reply into the database for the correct question.

Comment: Thanks for posting the controller, but it's still hard to tell what's going on - you aren't repeating anything in the code above.

Comment: This is just a snippet. I can post the entire thing so you can see what's happening if it helps.

Comment: Cheers, updated answer!

Comment: Thanks! I think I'm getting closer now. I have added the index and the also a String 'postAnswer' to the wrapper class, but I'm not sure how to get the value using the index. I tried to access it like this: wrapperQuestions[questionIndex]['postAnswer'] but it is throwing an error. I know I'm getting the right questionIndex value (I used System.Debug('===postAnswer===' + questionIndex); and got the right value).

Comment: Sorry, that syntax was wrong.  Try `wrapperQuestions[questionIndex].postAnswer`.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Just note that the index has to start with 0.

Comment: It seemed to work for the last reply box, but when I tested with the first one, I'm getting postAnswer as a null value. I've edited my post to include my save() function.

Comment: If you're taking the approach I suggested, this statement: `wrapperQuestions[questionIndex].postAnswer = postAnswer;` is the wrong way round.  It should be `postAnswer = wrapperQuestions[questionIndex].postAnswer;`.  If you're still having problems, please update all of the code above with the latest version.

Comment: I tried `postAnswer = wrapperQuestions[questionIndex].postAnswer;`, but it's still giving me a null value for the postAnswer value. I have 2 of these inputText fields on my test page and I'm able to post the second reply, but always get a null value for the first one.

Comment: actually, it's not working for either reply inputText now.

Comment: Please update your Visualforce code above to your latest version

Comment: I code above is the most up-to-date version.

Comment: The VF code above does not include any mention of `questionIndex`.

Comment: questionIndex is in the saveReply() function. You have to scroll to the bottom of the apex code portion. Just like you suggested: `postAnswer = wrapperQuestions[questionIndex].postAnswer;`

Comment: Please take another look at the second half of my answer - you need to update your VF page.

Comment: Sorry - VF page updated now. I updated the Apex code but forgot the VF code.

Comment: You still need to change the `value` of the `<apex:inputText />` element to `{!currentQuestion.postAnswer}` and `questionIndex` as another `<apex:param>` to the `<apex:commandButton>`

Comment: After adding the `{!currentQuestion.postAnswer}` code to the inpuText tag, I'm able to post to the second of the two reply fields, but not the first one.

Comment: In that case I'd use `System.debug()` to check the values of `wrapperQuestions` and `questionIndex` inside saveReply().

Comment: postAnswer = null;
questionIndex = 0;
wrapperQuestions = {WrapperQuestions:[bestReply=Reply:{Id=90719000000CaSeAAK, CreatedDate=2015-08-10 18:15:23, CreatedById=005a0000009bsmSAAQ, CreatorName=Sean, QuestionId=906190000008OPQAA2, Body=test - this is a test best answer!, UpVotes=0, DownVotes=0, CreatorSmallPhotoUrl=https://c.cs24.content.force.com/profilephoto/005/T, CommunityId=09a19000000CahKAAS}, postAnswer=null, question=Question:{Id=906190000008OPQAA2, CreatorSmallPhotoUrl=https://c.cs24.content.force.com/profilephoto/005/T, CreatorFullPhotoUrl=https://c.cs24.content.force.com/profileph...

Comment: Try adding a `rerender` attribute to the `<apex:commandbutton />`.  It doesn't matter what it's rerendering, it's just necessary to have that attribute to make the parameters work properly.  You could wrap the entire page contents in an `<apex:outputpanel id="pageContents"></apex:outputPanel>` and rerender that, if you like.

Comment: I already have a rerender on the commandButton. Both commandButtons have the same action. Could that be interfering somehow? I'm just surprised that the second inputText works with the commandButton, but the first one doesn't.

Comment: Hi slim, were you able to resolve this?  If not, try moving the `<apex:form>` tags so that they wrap your entire page.  In the debug log above, is `questionIndex = 0` correct - i.e. was it the first item that you clicked?

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for all your help on this. I did not get this resolved yet. I haven't worked on it since Friday. I will try wrapping the entire thing in `<apex:form>` currently, I have multiple form tags - could this be why?

Comment: I just recreated the issue in a sandbox, and wrapping everything in a single `<apex:form>` fixed it for me!  Hopefully it will for you too.  I did come across a different issue in the process - you need to rerender the `<apex:variable var="questionIndex" value="{!0}" />`.  You can do this by giving it an ID, e.g. `index`, and changing the commandButton rerender to `rerender="replies,index"`

Comment: I added the rerender and the index id but I'm still not getting this to work. I cannot post in either of my textInput fields and when I check the debug logs, I can see the correct index being pulled (either 0 or 1) but the postAnswer value is always null. Do you mind sharing your code from your test?

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't keep the test code.  Please update your question with the latest code and I'll see if I can spot anything

Comment: Added the code. I only added the rerender and the id `index` like you suggested in the last comment.

Comment: It doesn't look like you've moved the `<apex:form>` tags to wrap the entire page (i.e. outside the `<apex:repeat>` tags) - this is what fixed the issue in my test.

Comment: No, I did move the `<apex:form>` tag outside the repeater. I just forgot to include it in the code here.

Comment: Sorry slim, I can't spot any other issues. If this is in a sandbox and you want me to have a look, I'd be happy to. Otherwise, you should be able to raise a bounty on this question soon.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have the permissions to give you access to the sandbox. How about just the cls and page files?